# Integral representation of $\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}$

Tags: gamma-function

I am trying to find the integral representation of $\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}$ in the real axis and cant seem to find it. I know that this must have a standard representation but still cant find it.

Comment: *The* integral representation or *an* integral representation? [Hankel's formula](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.9.E2) works for all real (or complex) $z$.

Comment: Did you try to look in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_gamma_function ?